# Can be possible to acquire two semaphores at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

How I can do that a thead acquire two semaphores at the same time in java?

Comment: The short answer is no, but you may want to revise your question with more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common example is transferring money between two account object where is one is locked by a Semaphore.

> How I can do that a thead acquire two semaphores at the same time in java?

An obvious answer is to lock one and then the other. However this create deadlocks.

Instead you should sort the locks in some way (say based on a unique id in the accounts) so that you always lock them in the same order.